# Microsoft Windows Updates/Patches to be installed on Tridion servers

Tags: 2013, infrastructure

Can anyone tell me if it is OK to to install Microsoft Security Patches on all Tridion servers on regular basis (like once a month).

Do we have any guidelines/best practice to install Windows Patches on Tridion Servers?

Anyone encountered any issue with Tridion Content Manager or Publishing after installing any security patch??

Answer (score 3):

I've never had any issues with windows updates, the only one I've ever had to look out for is the java auto update, I always make sure this is turned off.

Comment: Chrome updates are usually painful, but never had issues with windows updates

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **"Always test ALL patches and changes in DEV and TEST environments before applying them in PROD"**. SDL can't possibly guarantee that future updates from another vendor won't impact the stability of their product.

That said, I have not had any issues in the past. I always leave automatic updates to download in my DEV instances, and manually install them and smoke test all functionality once a month in Tridion before allowing them to propagate to higher environments.

Like John said - be careful of Java updates, especially in the CD environment. I have not had Java update issues in the CM environment since the Business Connector was dropped.

Answer (score 2):

If it is SDL Tridion 2011 onwards (as you have mentioned), I have never faced any issue except if Java update is automatic as mentioned by John. For Tridion 5.x and 2009 (Which might not be the case for you) I can confirm that you will see a lots of issue as these Tridion versions are quite OLD, not in Support and have a lots of conflicts with Windows latest update.